# Localization failed to read a strings file (Xcode 6.3.2)

Tags: xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I can't export for localization, I just get a "Localization failed to read a strings file" error.

The system log says:

```
2015-06-07 01:41:48,305 Xcode[1914]: [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7718/IDEFoundation/Localization/IDELocalizationWork.m:434
Details:  Failed to read strings file "/var/folders/vh/z7jrdtc16mv_ml4rdf3c_yf40000gn/T/Xcode3SourceStringsAdaptor-8B1BF14F-E8BF-4354-9FB6-BFF843BD6623/Localizable.strings", underlying error:
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Object:   <IDELocalizationWork>
Method:   +readStringsWorkForContext:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa8a250a200>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

But I have no idea what file "Localizable.strings" is.
These steps didn't work:

- Found "Localizable.strings" in Base.lproj and deleted it. It was completely empty.
- Deleted the whole folder specified in the log message.
- Clean and Clean build folder.
- Running `genstrings` first to generate missing .strings-files. `genstrings` complained and said my strings weren't literals in the calls to `NSLocalizedString`. Uhh... they all look like this: `private let ALERT_REMINDER_FIRED_TITLE = NSLocalizedString("ALERT_REMINDER_FIRED_TITLE", tableName:"ReminderHandler", comment:"my comment")`

I figure that `Localizable.strings` is supposed to contain someting, like `/** no localizable strings **/` or something. The problem with that is that my project doesn't even contain the file, it's being generated as completely empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that unfinished and commented out calls to `NSLocalizedString` interfere with export for localization.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @Andreas What specifically did you change to fix this? What kind of calls to NSLocalizedString did you find that interfered with the export?

Comment: As the answer says, calls that were commented out, i.e.: `//NSLocalizedString(crapParameters)`

Answer (score 3):

For me it was like key = "your string"; that worked in swift 3.
No quotes for key. Semicolons at the end.

Comment: Edit this answer to clearly indicate that there should be semicolons at the end. I thought the answer suggests to remove semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when tried to use `NSLocalizedString` with own `NSBundle` specified. Seems Xcode won't work if you use localization macros with different form than `NSLocalizedString("Some key", comment: "Some comment")`. I have fixed this by just redefining the `NSLocalizedString` function like that:

```
public func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: String = "", comment: String) -> String
{
    return yourBundleHere.localizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName)
}
```

Replace `yourBundleHere` with `NSBundle.mainBundle()` or what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are redundant double quotation marks in your Localizable.strings file, then remove them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that I had completely empty xx.strings files - I'd manually cleared them out.

Add this line at the top of any empty xx.strings files, and the export works again:

```
/* No Localized Strings */
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. 
In my case it was caused by an `NSLocalizedString` that **used a variable** passed from the server **as the key instead of actual strings**. The system still scans commented code so anything short of **deleting the lines of code** will not work.